# 3-Book series on 'Set theory' 'Algebra' and 'Geometry'

Tags: reference-request, reference-works

I just read book on: 'Set theory and the Structure of Arithmetic by Hamilton and Landig'
This book mentioned 'This is first book in a series of 3 books' Where 2nd and 3rd book are on algebra and Geometry respectively. But I am not able to find even the titles of books anywhere. Can someone help me finding at least title of those books

Comment: It seems there are none : I've searched in Amazon and GoogleBooks, without results ... Sorry.

Comment: But first book is there and ebook also available on internet archive.

Comment: Here is the link to internet archive: https://archive.org/details/settheoryandthes000465mbp (I think you could have added the link to your post.)

Comment: Search in Google Scholar for [author:joseph-landin algebra](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=author:joseph-landin+algebra) suggest that there exists a book called *An introduction to algebraic structures* by Joseph Landin. But without actually seeing the book, it is difficult to say whether this might be the second volume.

Comment: And even more restrictive search for [author:joseph-landin](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=author:joseph-landin) reveals also the existence of something named *Axiomatic Theory of a Singular Non-Euclidean Plane*. But this was probably [his dissertation](http://www.genealogy.ams.org/id.php?id=43055).

Comment: @MartinSleziak yes exactly I need that book 'An introduction to algebraic structures by Joseph Landin' so that I can figure out whether it is second volume of that book or not. Maybe some day I'll buy that one